# How do I extract only number from dynamic headline/text?

Tags: java

I want to extract only number from dynamic header and then apply comparison logic to the same?
Header looks like - Rankings(20)
I want to extract only the number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One simple approach uses `String#replaceAll` with a capture group:

```java
String input = "Rankings(20)";
String num = input.replaceAll("\\S+\\((\\d+)\\)", "$1");
System.out.println(num);  // prints 20
```